# Composer class_alias and dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative, class SonataDoctrineSymfonyBundle not found?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata

I have a strange problem in production, where `composer dump-autoload --no-dev --classmap-authoritative` produces a classmap autoloader where classes defined using `class_alias` are not dumped. For example, take this two files from a real [Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/sonata-doctrine-extensions/tree/1.x/src/Bridge/Symfony):

- **[SonataDoctrineBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/sonata-doctrine-extensions/blob/1.x/src/Bridge/Symfony/SonataDoctrineBundle.php)** is the real class
- **[SonataDoctrineSymfonyBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/sonata-doctrine-extensions/blob/1.x/src/Bridge/Symfony/SonataDoctrineSymfonyBundle.php)** is defined using `class_alias`

The autoloader contains the first class:

```
root@09cc7fdd330c:/var/www/html# cat vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php | grep -i SonataDoctrineBundle
    'Sonata\\Doctrine\\Bridge\\Symfony\\Bundle\\SonataDoctrineBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sonata-project/doctrine-extensions/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/SonataDoctrineBundle.php',
    'Sonata\\Doctrine\\Bridge\\Symfony\\SonataDoctrineBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sonata-project/doctrine-extensions/src/Bridge/Symfony/SonataDoctrineBundle.php',
```

... but not the second one.

As a consequence, I'm getting errors in production:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Sonata\Doctrine\Bridge\Symfony\SonataDoctrineSymfonyBundle' not found in /var/www/html/src/Kernel.php:38

**Question is: why I cannot autoload class `SonataDoctrineSymfonyBundle`?**

(I can fix this problem changing this specific class of course, but I don't know where `class_alias` maybe used across the entire `vendor` directory).

Comment: You've commanded composer to create an autoloader with an autoritative classmap. that means the classmap is not only leading, but everything not in the classmap is not going to be loaded.

Comment: Yes, i Know. But having the class_alias means that the class will never be dumped into the classmap? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: That is the answer. If you have the source, make the answer and i'll accept it :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `composer dump-autoload` command with the `--classmap-authoritative` command line argument prevents any other auto-loading next to the classmap.

This mechanism is part of the [*Composer Autoloader optimization*¹](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md), more specifically, it is the [*Optimization Level 2/A: Authoritative class maps*²](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md#optimization-level-2-a-authoritative-class-maps).

> This option [-a, --classmap-authoritative] says that if something is not found in the classmap, then it does not exist and the autoloader should not attempt to look on the filesystem according to PSR-4 rules.

When Composer generates the class-map, it does not take files with `class_alias()` directives into account³. That means, classes which names only appear as parameters to calls of `class_alias()` do **not** become part of the class-map.

As it seems you don't have the requirement to use this autoloader optimization and it is incompatible with the `class_alias` use, an alternative is to use Composer autoload optimization level 1 only:

```
$ composer dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize
```

*(use of `--optimize` (short: `-o`) command line argument)*

Otherwise it might work using concrete classes instead of `class_alias()`, but this depends if the library in use supports a different, more static alternative. If so however, then generating the "real" classes before dumping the classmap may help you retain the optimization level 2/A.

---

¹ [Composer Autoloader optimization](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md)

² [Optimization Level 2/A: Authoritative class maps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md#optimization-level-2-a-authoritative-class-maps)

³ at least not at the time of writing this answer per its [source](https://github.com/composer/composer), with additional discussion of the topic in [*Support for class aliases #5873*](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5873)